# C++ Matrix Multiplication - understanding the logic behind an optimized method for it

Tags: c++, matrix

Ive been recently reading Matrix Tutorials with openGL and stumbled upon an optimized method for Matrix Multiplication that I cannot understand.

```
//Create an allias type for a Matrix Type      
typedef struct Matrix
{
    float m[16];
} Matrix;

//default matrix
static const Matrix IDENTITY_MATRIX = { {
    1, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 1
} };

Matrix MultiplyMatrices(const Matrix* m1, const Matrix* m2)
{
    Matrix out = IDENTITY_MATRIX;
    unsigned int row, column, row_offset;

    for (row = 0, row_offset = row * 4; row < 4; ++row, row_offset = row * 4)
        for (column = 0; column < 4; ++column)
            out.m[row_offset + column] =
            (m1->m[row_offset + 0] * m2->m[column + 0]) +
            (m1->m[row_offset + 1] * m2->m[column + 4]) +
            (m1->m[row_offset + 2] * m2->m[column + 8]) +
            (m1->m[row_offset + 3] * m2->m[column + 12]);

    return out;
}
```

These are the questions I have:

1. In the method **MultiplyMatrices** why is there a pointer to params m1 and m2? If your just copying their values and returning a new matrix why use a pointer?
2. Why is the for loop condition **identical** to its increment?

> for (row = 0, **row_offset = row * 4**; row < 4; ++row, **row_offset = row *
>   4**)

Comment: Can I please edit and delete the second question. Its a viewing error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MultiplyMatrices` function calculates the product of two matrices. So that's why you need two matrices as the input arguments of this function. Note that the definition of the matrix

```
typedef struct Matrix
{
    float m[16];
} Matrix;
```

defines a 4 by 4 matrix with a 1-D array. So the offset is 4 for each row. This is just to simulate a 2-D matrix with 1-D array. You need to pass in pointers to two input matrices so that you can get their element values inside the function.

The reason why you see two identical statements in the for loop is:

```
for (row = 0, row_offset = row * 4; row < 4; ++row, row_offset = row * 4)
```

Initially the `row_offset` is set to 0. When the loop is going through each row in the matrix, the `row_offset` is increasing with `row`. This is because in the 1-D array representation of 2-D matrix, the a[i][j] element can be written as:

```
a[i][j] = a[i*num_col+j]
```

And here `num_col` is 4. So these two statements are not the same. The first is to initialize. The second is to reset the `row_offset` when the row index increases by 1.

Comment: "You need to pass in pointers to two input matrices so that you can get their element values inside the function." - Is this a rule in C ~ do you need to pass 'every' object array type with a pointer so you can access its individual elements? I'm still confused about this

Comment: Array in C or vanilla C++ is better to pass into a function as a pointer. You can think array as a block of continuous memory and use a pointer to get the first element's address. This way it is very efficient to do array indexing in the function.

Answer (score 0):

> In the method MultiplyMatrices why is there a pointer to m1 and m2? If your just copying their values why use a pointer?

Maybe I don't understand your question, but how would you propose to do it differently? You're outputting the product into a third memory location `out` which is the product of `m1` and `m2`. This is the most efficient way..

> Why is the for loop condition identical to its increment?

It's not - the `++row` increments `row` before the assignment on each loop. The "condition" is `row < 4` which you did not bold - maybe that's the confusion.

Comment: (please excuse my lack of knolwedge of C) From the way I see it you only use pointers if you want to modify the original value listed in the parameters of a function. i.e. Pass by value. Why is it using Pass by Reference? Also thankyou with the second question